# The QS parameter in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there a way in the subscriber data views to pull the QS parameter and tie it to the email address?

My preference page out of the box requires a link that looks like this:
http://click.mycompany.com/subscription_center.aspx?qs=1254d66fa63a4b547cd28f0acc9eb76e91214d6ee1406dbbe50aaebef0a990863543b31083477062c36b7ab7efb89c81facdf867248411da4c4bba974f9fca7ff784f77f3447928f

I am wondering if I can send this QS parameter along with the email address to an outside agency who needs to unsubscribe users to our marketing cloud preference center.

Answer (score 1):

you can find most elements that the QS parameter encrypts individually, but you cannot find the encrypted form anywhere except in the email itself.

Starting from there: what you can do is log the value of the entire rendered link in a data extension at the time of send next to the email address. With some delay (e.g. hourly), you could send that link and the email address to an external system from the send log data extension. Real time during sendout, probably not as you would run into performance and reliability issues in case the connection breaks.

As a quick test:
Set up a DE "logDE" with two fields, email and profilecenter.
Add this to a message, send a preview out to yourself.

```
%%[

SET @profileURL = profile_center_url
SET @upsert = UpsertDE("logde",1,"email",emailaddr,"profilecenter",@profileURL)

]%%
```

Result: *your* email and *your* profile center link are in the data extension.
Set up an hourly automation to do whatever you want with it.

Your sendout performance will be slowed technically, but not to an alarming extent, depending on the size of your sendouts, maybe not even noticeably so. Be sure to load test in case minutes matter for your sendouts, but generally speaking, this approach should work also for sendouts in the millions.

Comment: Jonas, thank you for this solution. I was thinking of this idea too, during sendtime where the url is upserted. As you have stated, I guess I cannot pull this from the subscriber data views or any SQL. Or, do you mean there is a location to pull the QS from outside of sendtime? "you can find most elements that the QS parameter encrypts individually, but you cannot find the encrypted form anywhere except in the email itself." At the very least I am trying to batch ~15000 users for the initial load to the outside agency.

Comment: The QS param contains things like subscriberkey, jobid etc. Of course you will find those in the data views. But they are a) generated at send time and b) are not useful to you here, as they alone don't make a functional,  i.e. encrypted link. So essentially, you are creating your own "pseudo data view". It's being written to at send time, but its being populated with the thing you need, not individual parts of it. This starts working once you start upserting data from your emails. If you haven't done this in any mails yet, you cannot find their generated links anywhere else, unfortunately.